# Pull-down resistor and voltage on DO

Tags: arduino, voltage, ground, pulldown

I am currently having an issue with DOs on an Arduino in a constant state of high with a pull-down resistor attached to a ground plane. Voltage measured on the DO is 3 V. The pull-down resistor is 2.2 kΩ.

Below is the wiring diagram of the entire circuit.

I am looking for suggestions on where I went wrong with this, or possible solutions.

Currently I am thinking of either using a larger resistor array or putting a diode between the resistors and the ground plane.

[image]

Comment: Are your pins configured as inputs with no pull-ups?

Comment: So I understand that you measuring the voltage between pins D2...D7 and a ground, and this voltage is 3V. Also I understand that the dip switch SW1 is closed (i.e. connects D2-D7 to 5V)?

Comment: yup, using a fluke when measuring from D2-D7 to a ground pin i am seeing 3 volts with the switches in the open state. when the switches are closed 5 volts are measured. when switches are opened again 3v are measured.

Comment: That's seems really strange. 1) Are pins for sure configured as inputs (not outputs)? 2) If so, then are those inputs with no pull ups? 3) Is the Atmega for sure powered from 5V? I see some 3.3 on the schematic as well. And some Arduino boards work with 3.3V.

Comment: So after a good meal and a break from beating my head against the desk found the issue. turn out that the through holes on the pcb for the arduino are not connected to the ground plane on the pcb. all GND connects that are not on the arduino were connected to the ground plane. Thanks for the suggestions and if anyone has any input on the circuit above your more then welcome to express them as I will need to look over everything and send the drawings back out for the boards to be manufactured again

Comment: If the microcontroller on the Arduino is operating on 3.3 volts (as I suspect, since you show a 3.3V pin on the Arduino), the switches should be connected to 3.3 V, not 5 V - you should not pull the microcontroller's inputs above it Vcc supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT);           // set pin as input (no pull-up resistor)   
pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);    // set pin as input (20k-50k internal pull-up resistor)   

pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);          // set pin as output
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);       // drive pin to Vcc
digitalWrite(pin, LOW);        // drive pin to GND
```

Be [ESD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=esd) Aware....

Comment: I don't recall Atmega (used in Arduino) to have pull-down capabilities. Atmega has only pull up. Besides, both pull-up or pull-down wouldn't do 3V out of 5V with 2.2K external pull down.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins  I wonder if all input pins are the same.

Comment: So according to your link, you should edit your answer and remove this "internal pulldown" - there is no such thing. `digitalWrite(pin, LOW);` will not turn on pull down - it will just disable pull-up resistors, making an input go into high impedance state.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, i took the liberty to change your answer, i hope you do not mind